# develop custom progressdialog android

Tags: android, progressdialog

I am developing a multi device android app. All are working fine but for 2 things. The progress dialog and the toast which appears very small in android but perfectly good in S2. Can anyone please suggest any workaround for the same to either increase the size of toast and progress and oblige. I have already mentioned screen support in the manifest but no use.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom toast, where you can define your own layout. checkout the code below.

XML layout named as “custom_toast.xml”

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toast_layout_root"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp" >

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#00AAE9"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp" >

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/toastImage"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:src="@drawable/ic_warning" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/toastText"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textSize="7pt"
android:textStyle="italic" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Your activity class

```
package com.javatechig.droid.ui;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Button toastButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.toastButton);
toastButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
//create the toast object, set display duration,
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is a plain toast.",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
});

Button customToastButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.customToastButton);
customToastButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {

//get the LayoutInflater and inflate the custom_toast layout
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, (ViewGroup)
findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

//get the TextView from the custom_toast layout
TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toastText);
text.setText("This is my custom toast");

//create the toast object, set display duration,
//set the view as layout that's inflated above and then call show()
Toast t = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
t.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
t.setView(layout);
t.show();
}
});

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}

}
```

Output below

[image: Output below]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can we do the same for progressbar as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can set View for any type of dialog or toast to have custom look.Toast sample is mentioned below the same applies for Alert or progress dialog.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate
(R.layout.custom_toast,(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));  
TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text); text.setText("This is a custom toast"); 
Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext()); 
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG); 
toast.setView(layout); toast.show();
```